# Show spinner when using switcherbutton

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/switcher_button) package to create a switcherbutton. When the switch is toggled either way, a dialog pop up appears and when someone presses okay on the dialog pop up, some data is saved in the database and then the switch flips. There is this issue with the following code.

1. When the switch button is toggled, the switch does not flip until the value is saved in DB. This creates an illusion to the user that perhaps maybe the toggle does not work. How can I handle this scenario such that user sees maybe a loading spinner to notify them that their requested changes are being taken care of?

Here's the code:

```
SwitcherButton(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  value: isSwitchOn,
                  onColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                  offColor: Colors.grey,
                  onChange: (value) {
                    print(value);
                    AwesomeDialog(
                      context: context,
                      dialogType: DialogType.QUESTION,
                      animType: AnimType.TOPSLIDE,
                      title: isSwitchOn
                          ? 'Mark item as unavailable ?'
                          : 'Mark item as available?',
                      desc: '',
                      btnCancelOnPress: () {
                        setState(() {
                          // isSwitchOn=!value;
                          print(
                              'Value after cancel is ' + isSwitchOn.toString());
                        });
                      },
                      btnOkText: "Yes",
                      btnCancelText: "No",
                      btnOkOnPress: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isSwitchOn = !isSwitchOn;
                          updateProductAvailability(isSwitchOn);
                        });
                      },
                    )..show();
                  },
                ),

 updateProductAvailability(bool isSwitchOn) async {
    await Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
        .updateProductAvailability(widget.id, isSwitchOn)
        .then((value) => Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: isSwitchOn
                    ? Text('Product marked as available')
                    : Text('Product marked as unavailable'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            )).catchError((Object error){
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content:Text('Something went wrong. Please try again later.'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            );
            });
  }
```

**Updated Answer based On Nick's response.**

```
_isLoading?CircularProgressIndicator():SwitcherButton(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  value: isSwitchOn,
                  onColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                  offColor: Colors.grey,
                  onChange: (value) {
                    value=!value;
                    AwesomeDialog(
                      context: context,
                      dialogType: DialogType.QUESTION,
                      animType: AnimType.TOPSLIDE,
                      title: isSwitchOn
                          ? 'Mark item as unavailable ?'
                          : 'Mark item as available?',
                      desc: '',
                      btnCancelOnPress: () {
                        setState(() {
                          // isSwitchOn=!value;
                          print(
                              'Value after cancel is ' + isSwitchOn.toString());
                        });
                      },
                      btnOkText: "Yes",
                      btnCancelText: "No",
                      btnOkOnPress: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isSwitchOn = !isSwitchOn;
                          //print('isswitchon value is ' + isSwitchOn.toString());
                         updateProductAvailability(isSwitchOn);
                        });
                      },
                    )..show();
                  },
                ),

 updateProductAvailability(bool isSwitchOn) async {
     setState((){
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    
    await Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
        .updateProductAvailability(widget.id, isSwitchOn)
        .then((value) {
              
              // <---------------------------
              setState((){
                _isLoading = false;
              });

              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: isSwitchOn
                    ? Text('Product marked as available')
                    : Text('Product marked as unavailable'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            );}).catchError((Object error){

              // <---------------------------
              setState((){
                _isLoading = false;
              });

                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content:Text('Something went wrong. Please try again later.'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            );
            });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The future takes some time to complete.
Using a variable to `isLoading` to maintain loading logic can help.
Below is the example.

Define a variable isLoading in State Class.

```dart
bool isLoading = false;
```

Now use this in your Widget tree wherever required.

```dart
isLoading ? AnySpinnerWidget() : ShowAlternativeWidget()
```

Mark it true and false according and call `setState` to update the UI.

```dart
updateProductAvailability(bool isSwitchOn) async {

    // <---------------------------
    setState((){
      isLoading = true;
    });
    
    await Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
        .updateProductAvailability(widget.id, isSwitchOn)
        .then((value) {
              
              // <---------------------------
              setState((){
                isLoading = false;
              });

              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: isSwitchOn
                    ? Text('Product marked as available')
                    : Text('Product marked as unavailable'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            )}).catchError((Object error){

              // <---------------------------
              setState((){
                isLoading = false;
              });

                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content:Text('Something went wrong. Please try again later.'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            );
            });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for showspinner please?

Comment: Any widget you want to use for showing the spinning. I just used it as an example. Most commonly used is [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html)

Comment: This works fine with one minor glitch. When updateProductAvailability is executed, the spinner just stucks for atleast 3 seconds and then resumes spinning. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: I can't tell without looking at the code. This might a different issue. Depends on how you've implemented it.

Comment: @bangbang Do you want to stop the spinner before snackbar shows or after snackbar is gone ?

Comment: Either way is fine.

Comment: Then the solution should work. I can't say about the spinner stuck situation with current information.

Comment: Please see the updated code and let me know if you have enough visibility or you would like to see more code.

Comment: Try removing `setState` inside `btnOkOnPress`. I didn't focus on this before. This might be the problem.